# Images are not displayed in Google Assistant rich response only on Android devices

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I have a servlet with a valid HTTPS certificate that serves up a PNG datastream. When I add a URL link to it in a Basic Card response, the image is displayed in Google Assistant simulator (in my PC browser), on iPhone and iPad. However, the image is NOT displayed on my OnePlus 6T (with latest updates) or my daughter's Samsung S10. This link opens correctly from Google Chrome on the same devices.

This can be easily reproduced by  creating a Basic Card with following URL (public access):

https://wm.mysmarterwindow.com/iswms-client/WMImageServlet?line_id=5676&rand=0.9008262464587079

I am at my wits end here - could it be that Google Assistant works better on an apple device???

Comment: same issue! And I have a OnePlus6T.